# How to check if a string is smaller than another, in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, string, compare

I have two strings given as arguments to a Haskell function.

`s1` is smaller than `s2` if `s1` is shorter than `s2` or if they have the same length and `s1` is lexicographically smaller than `s2`.

How do I implement this in Haskell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use something like the following:

```
smaller :: String -> String -> Bool
smaller s1 s2 | len1 /= len2         = (len1 < len2)
              | otherwise            = (s1 < s2)
              where (len1, len2) = (length s1, length s2)
```

Here's a sample run, in Hugs:

```
Main> smaller "b" "aa"
True
Main> smaller "aa" "b"
False
Main> smaller "this" "that"
False
Main> smaller "that" "this"
True
```

Comment: This is obviously faster than my version, since it only computes the length of the strings once. It can probably be made even faster by doing a direct pattern match on the input strings, thereby merging this definition and the definition of the `length` function.

Comment: Haskell is all about generalization and good coding practices, and it has a very good type (class) system. Why not rewrite the function as `compare' :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Ordering` or so?

Comment: @Aleksander: It depends what the OP wants.  Since the OP has asked a fairly elementary question, perhaps he/she wants an elementary answer?  I don't doubt that there are faster and/or more idiomatic ways to write such a function in Haskell, but perhaps it's better to keep things simple to help the OP learn.

Answer (score 7):

The one-pass solution:

```
lengthcompare :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Ordering
lengthcompare = lc EQ
 where
  lc lx [] [] = lx
  lc _ [] _ = LT
  lc _ _ [] = GT
  lc EQ (v:vs) (w:ws) = lc (compare v w) vs ws
  lc lx (_:vs) (_:ws) = lc lx vs ws

smaller :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
smaller s1 s2 = lengthcompare s1 s2 == LT
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
compare s1 s2
```

(This returns LT, EQ, or GT).

Comment: I think the OP wants shorter strings to be 'smaller' than longer strings regardless of their contents.  compare "b" "aa" returns GT, but I think the OP would want a function that returns LT in this case.

Answer (score 4):

An shorter version of the `mappend` version by Tom Lokhorst above:

```
import Data.Monoid (mappend)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

compareStrings :: String -> String -> Ordering
compareStrings = comparing length `mappend` comparing id
```

Another way, taking advantage of the ordering of tuples:

```
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))

compareStrings :: String -> String -> Ordering
compareStrings = comparing (length &&& id)
```

Comment: Oh right, I was thinking of an alternative definition, but when defining a new function, you can obviously use the existing ordering on lists. Nice definitions!

Comment: Also, I really need to start learning the Arrows library. I continuously see people coming up with these nice elegant definitions, and that's just using the function instances...

Comment: Yes, these are nice and short.

comparing id == compare, so here's another alternative:

comparing length `mappend` compare

Answer (score 2):

`String` is an instance of [`Ord`](http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/Ord_c.html) and therefore you can use all of those methods to lexicographically compare string. As Andrew said, that's essentially `compare` but also the comparison operators, `(<)` among others.

```
smaller :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
smaller a b = a < b
```

This works for *all types* implementing `Ord` (and is really just a crude wrapper for `(<)`), including `String`.

Comment: I think the OP wants shorter strings to be 'smaller' than longer strings regardless of their contents.  For example, smaller "b" "aa" should return True.  (<) doesn't take lengths into account so I don't believe your answer is quite what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

The normal string compare only works on lexicographical ordering, not the length of strings.

So you'd have to write your own function to also check for the length:

```
smaller :: String -> String -> Bool
smaller s1 s2 | length s1 < length s2 = True
              | length s1 > length s2 = False 
              | otherwise             = s1 < s2
```

Or a bit more general:

```
compareStrings :: String -> String -> Ordering
compareStrings s1 s2 | length s1 < length s2 = LT
                     | length s1 > length s2 = GT
                     | otherwise             = compare s1 s2
```

Example:

```
ghci> compare "ab" "z"
LT
ghci> compareStrings "ab" "z"
GT
```

---

We were toying around with Monoids at university last week, and we came up with this lovely alternative `Ord` instance:

```
instance Ord a => Ord [a] where
  compare = comparing length
              `mappend` comparing head `mappend` comparing tail
```

But if you don't quite understand this, I suggest you stick with the first definition ;-)

Comment: Part of the reason comparing lengths is useful is many implementations of String in other languages store or cache the string length. The benefit is that most string comparisons will then take time O(1) as a function of the lengths of the strings. That is not the case in Haskell. All String comparisons with the native implementation will take time at least O(min(m,n)) as a function of the lengths of the strings.

Comment: Sure, and this isn't even the fastest implementation possible. It's just that I thought the questioner asked for a version of compare where the strings were first checked for length before lexicographical order. This might be useful if you want to print a list of strings and think it prettier to print smaller strings first.

Comment: @Tom: I'm not sure your smaller function works correctly if s2 is longer than s1.  For example, smaller "aa" "b" returns True.  It seems to me that the OP wants the function to return False in this case.